# UI selenium Test in Azure devops Release

Tags: selenium-webdriver, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to create a release pipeline with IIS deployment and after that, there is UI Selenium test project.

Everything is working fine except the file uploader. How to handle file uploader?
VSTS Agent is not allowing to get the file from the project folder.
I tried to put the file in Sharepoint and get the stream from there and try to save in the project directory but still, it is not allowing to save file.

```
var directory = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(HelperClass)).Location;
Console.WriteLine(directory); var newDir = 
directory.Replace("\\bin\\Release\\MarloTest.dll", "\\bin\\Release"); 
Console.WriteLine(newDir); 

if (Directory.Exists(newDir)) return newDir;

(var file= new FileStream(newPath, FileMode.Create)) 
{ 
   var streamFile = stream; streamFile.CopyTo(file); 
}
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you share the code you use to get the file. Are you sure the Current working directory is actually the folder you expect? How are you resolving the Project Folder? What test framework are you using to drive the Selenium test?

Comment: @jessehouwing 

By this path, I am getting the directory of project execution dll on azure devops agents.
`var directory = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(HelperClass)).Location;
            Console.WriteLine(directory);
            var newDir = directory.Replace("\\bin\\Release\\MarloTest.dll", "\\bin\\Release");
            Console.WriteLine(newDir);
            if (Directory.Exists(newDir))
                return newDir;
`

Comment: @jessehouwing

For saving file I am using this code
`using (var file= new FileStream(newPath, FileMode.Create))
            {
                var streamFile = stream;
                streamFile.CopyTo(file);
            }`

In local, this is working fine but not on devops azure agent HostedVS2017 on which
test assembly is running.

Comment: Can you edit the question above, instead of putting the code here in the comments? It's hard to read and others coming onto this question will need to put together the pieces of the puzzle.

Answer (score -1):

What agents are you using to fire your UI tests from your release pipeline? If its Hosted agent, I doubt it works. Try installing the agent of your own and trigger a release. For running Selenium UI tests, you can refer [here](https://www.azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vstsextend/Selenium/).

Comment: Why doubt whether it works? Hosted Agent runs interactively and is configured to support running UI tests